# Update field after success payment

Tags: laravel

Hello i'm using paytabs for payment , Trying to update value from 0 to 1 after success payment

```
public function return(Request $request): string
{
    $validSignature = $this->validateSignature($request->all());

    if ($validSignature) {
        if ($request->respStatus == 'A') {
            $transaction = Transaction::where('paytabs_transaction_reference', $request->tranRef)->first();
            $transaction->paid = true;
            $transaction->save();
            
            DB::table('carts')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('opened', 0 )->update(['opened' => 1]);

            return 'Paid Message ' . $request->respMessage;
        }
        return 'Unpaid Message ' . $request->respMessage;
    } else {
        return 'Invalid  Transaction Signature';
    }
}
```

But nothing changes.. any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public function return(Request $request): string
{
    $validSignature = $this->validateSignature($request->all());

    if(is_null($validSignature)){
        return 'Invalid  Transaction Signature';
    }

    if ($request->respStatus != 'A') {
        return 'Unpaid Message ' . $request->respMessage;
     }

    try{
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $transaction = Transaction::where('paytabs_transaction_reference', $request->tranRef)->first();
        $transaction->paid = true;
        $transaction->save();

       DB::table('carts')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('opened', 0)->update(['opened' => 1]);

       DB::commit();
       return 'Paid Message ' . $request->respMessage;
    }catch(Exception $exception){
        DB::rollback();
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```